# DateTime value is sometimes infinity in DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity column

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Postgres + EF Core 7.

I have a bug which I can't reproduce so open for ideas. All my entities are inheriting from this class:

```
public abstract class Auditable
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }

    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class User : Auditable //...

_dbContext.Users.Update(user);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem is the `DateCreated` column which generates the proper value on insert but sometimes it is replaced with `infinity` on update. It's declared as private so I can't even change it by changing the entity.

What is the possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: Is it changed to `infinity` in the database or just locally?

Comment: @AndrewMorton in the database, not sure if infinity is possible in .net at all